# Where to place validation of entities in DDD?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I would like to confirm / clarify if my presumption about DDD entities validation is correct.

For example - I have a domain object `WorkReport`, this object contains one or more activities `WorkReportActivity`, there is a `addNewActivity` to append new activity:

```
public void addNewActivity(final WorkReportActivity activity) {
    activities.put(activity.getId(), activity);
}
```

**Question:**

I would like to know where to place checking / validation that instance of `WorkReportActivity` is valid so report can accept it and won't contain invalid data.

Is it sufficient to **do not** allow to create `WorkReportActivity` instance with invalid parameters and do validation in `WorkReportActivity` constructor? Sometime there will be more views what is a valid instance, with respect to different use cases in application.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know where to place checking / validation that instance of WorkReportActivity is valid so report can accept it and won't contain invalid data.

Typically: in the constructor/factory method that creates the activity.

The basic idea being that you have a single choke point where data can be assembled into a particular `type`, and after that the type checker is able to enforce the guarantees that the rest of the code needs.

If your implementation language doesn't include "strong" type checking, you may need a bit of clever.  ([domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) started in the Java world, where these checks are available at design time).

Caution: there are actually two different kinds of validation associated with entities.  Ensuring that a "state" is valid -- consistent with the assumptions that will be made about it -- is usually done in the value object(s) that represent that state.  But you may also need to validate whether or not the entity is allowed to transition from one valid state to another.

(This validation is usually implicit -- we often have the entity calculate its own next state from its current state, with that calculating ensuring that the transition will be valid).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should validate in the constructor of any domain object that the instance you are creating is valid, regardless of who calls the constructor. You must concentrate all the validation rules in one method and call it from the constructor.